# Setting up dockerized Couchdb with python

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, environment-variables, couchdb

Long story short I need to extend [apache/couchdb/](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/couchdb/) Dockerfile so that would do some magic processing to get 2 values (username and password) and then start the couchdb instance with an admin.

Normally you would do it by running `docker run ... -e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password couchdb` but I may not know the values beforehand and I want those to be retrieve from somewhere every time container is starting.

I made a Dockerfile that looks more or less like this:

```
FROM couchdb:2.1.1
RUN apt-get update --force-yes && apt-get install -y python3
RUN curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "/app/start_couch.py"]
```

Where `start_couch.py` looks like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

user,password = very_complex_stuff()

os.environ['COUCHDB_USER'] = user
os.environ['COUCHDB_PASSWORD'] = password

subprocess.call(["/opt/couchdb/bin/couchdb"], env=os.environ)
```

yet when build and run my image the couchdb starts without an pre-set admin (I mean i can do everything without login)

Can someone point out what am i doing wrong or suggest a different solution?

The criteria is that admin credentials are taken from a python script (function) and it needs to executed on `docker run`

Comment: After `user,password = very_complex_stuff()` statement, can you log the `user` and `password` to see if they are actually assigned correctly? I mean to check if they are not `null` or empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistery solved

that image have a custom entrypoint `ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`, so the `-e` switch sets up env vars before the `.sh` is execute however my python script is run later.

I fix this by changing adding to Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]
CMD ["python3", "/app/start_couch.py"]
```

and calling couch from python like this:

```
subprocess.call(
    ["/docker-entrypoint.sh", "/opt/couchdb/bin/couchdb"],
    env=os.environ
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... couchdb starts without a pre-set admin (I mean i can do everything
>   without login) ...

That's called [The Admin Party](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/security.html#the-admin-party) which is the default configuration if you don't modify the security configurations of CouchDB. It will start to make sense if you take a look at the documentation.

Comment: I did, setting env vars `COUCHDB_USER` and `COUCHDB_PASSWORD` should prevent that and it does when i start my container with -e switch, but setting them in python and calling subprocess does not work for some reason.

Comment: @Kazz Thanks. I didn't get your situation before. Now I'm more clear.